# Are there etl conversion tools that can convert a single job or multiple jobs?

Tags: etl

Are there etl conversion tools that can convert a single job or multiple jobs in one go and without taking much time.

Answer (score 0):

AnalytixDS claims to do this with their Litespeed Conversion product.

http://analytixds.com/litespeed-conversion/

A long list of the tools they claim to convert is about half way down the page.

I don't know anything more about it than I have read on their web site, but I've not seen any other product make this claim.